# Mis archivos de php se autoeliminan al ejecutarlos en el terminal

Tags: php, git, archivo, vscode, eliminar

Mi problema es que a la hora de ejecutar un archivo php en el terminal (he probado tanto en bash como en powershell), por ejemplo mediante el siguiente código *php database/connection.php* (para comprobar si mi conexión a la base de datos está funcionando) , ese archivo se ejecuta y automáticamente se elimina. Además, git no me permite restaurar el archivo.

Os muestro:

**ls con los archivos que tengo dentro de la carpeta api:**

```
  $ ls
agregarUsuario.php  conexion.php  obtenerUsuarios.php



 Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    borrarUsuario.php

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ../.gitignore
        ../composer.json
```

**Ejecuto el archivo:**

```
 php obtenerUsuarios.php
[{"idUsuario":"1","usuario":"Marcos","contrasena":"marcos123","email":"marcos123@gmail.com"},{"idUsuario":"2","usuario":"Luc\u00eda","contrasena":"luci123","email":"luci123@hotmail.com"}]
```

**ls de nuevo:**

```
  ls
agregarUsuario.php  conexion.php
```

**Git status de nuevo:**

```
  git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    editarUsuario.php

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    borrarUsuario.php
        deleted:    obtenerUsuarios.php

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ../.gitignore
        ../composer.json
```

Como veis, el archivo que he ejecutado, y que efectivamente me trajo los datos que le pedía, al momento desapareció. ¿Podéis ayudarme a identificar qué está pasando, y a ponerle solución?

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: cuando dices "terminal" te refieres a bash? y pones "literal" esto <php path/to/file.php>? si es eso, bash no funciona así, prueba: php file.php sin <>

Comment: ¿Qué operativo? ¿qué escribes exactamente en la terminal? quiero decir, pones las comillas y los signos <, > ? ¿no deberías poner simplemente `php path/to/file.php` ?

Comment: @JéssicaRios, Para que se notifique a quienes te hicieron preguntas de tu respuesta, escribe "@nombreUsuario" y tu respuesta.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No sé cómo puedo aclarar más el problema. Mi problema es que se eliminan los archivos cuando escribo en el terminal php database/connection.php o similares para comprobar que el código funciona. Y no quiero que se eliminen...

Comment: Bienvenida, @JéssicaRíos! Podrías hacer un `ls` y un `git status` que muestre un archivo que vas a ejecutar, entonces ejecútalo y entonces vuelves a mostrar `ls` y `git status` que muestre que el archivo ya no está. Y, de paso, mostrarnos el comando que estás ejecutando para tratar de recuperar el archivo (y que no te deja). Por si acaso: No lo pongas como comentarios, Edita la pregunta original y agrega la info (y, también importante: como texto, no pongas un screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, el problema era que el antivirus (avast) enviaba los archivos a una carpeta de seguridad después de ejecutarlos, de forma que no se podían restaurar desde el terminal en vscode, sino sólo desde la interfaz del antivirus.

Gracias por vuestras respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Ya veo que tienes la respuesta a la razón por la cual el archivo desaparecía. Ahora, en base a lo que veo en la salida de `git status` luego de que el archivo desaparece, te indico como recuperarlo usando git:

```
git restore -- obtenerUsuarios.php
```

Con eso le estás pidiendo a git que coloque el archivo en el *árbol de trabajo* a partir de como está el archivo en el `index`. Y, claro está, eso es sin tomar en cuenta lo que el antivirus quiera hacer.